# How can I insert each line from txt file into separate rows in a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel

I have a text file which has words from dictionary like..

```
ABACA
ABACHI
ABACHISTA
ABACO
ABADESSA
ABADIA
ABALIETA
ABARICA
```

Now what I want to do is insert this list from a text file into a SQL Server table. I can not possibly add quotes manually. I think one way of doing this could be copy pasting this into Excel sheet and then importing it or adding quotes but Excel sheet has like 65k rows in a sheet and this text file has much greater number of words in it. So how can this be done easily? I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: How are you currently trying?

Comment: I tried doing it with excel but there are just too many rows for excel.

Comment: Use a regex on the file to create insert statements.  Or use a programatic approach to load the file using a prepared statement and doing it in batches.  Or use a tool like pentaho to import data.  There are three options for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've tagged your question with C#, Just use:

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

to get all of the lines, run on all of them with a `foreach` and use whatever way you want to insert it to your database, You can use:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [YourTable] ([YourColumn]) VALUES (:val)";

            var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = ":val";
            param.Value = line;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested that but it's simple enough to succeed with not much trouble.

I geuss it'll be better to send all the inserts in a single command, but that's just a p.o.c.

Comment: I wanted to know another means apart from import functionality since it does not give any control over manipulation of data. This is what i was expecting C# code.

Answer (score 10):

You can easily bulk import a **huge** file with a lot of words using T-SQL - just create a table with a single column of type `varchar`, long enough to hold your longest string, and then bulk insert your data.

Try to use T-SQL statements something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ImportedWordList(Word VARCHAR(200) )

BULK INSERT ImportedWordList
FROM 'c:\temp\listofwords.txt'
WITH
(ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.ImportedWordList
```

Works like a charm in my limited testing (and takes about 20 seconds to load a list of over a million words into that table).

Comment: I knew that this can be done in many ways and i was looking forward to  something new.

Answer (score 2):

Do you only have to do this once?

[Open up management studio and use Import Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Rmi.png)

choose Flat File Source as the data source

Comment: Pretty much this, right-click on the database you want to insert it into, click Tasks -> Import Data.  Select 'flat file source' and point it to the txt file, it will show you preview, allow you to rename the table its heading into, and set data types.  If the preview shows them all as one line, not one per row, then your file doesn't have a good row delimiter, you can adjust the row delimiter, but you likely won't have to.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an example.

```
string str = null;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(YourTextFilePath);
using (var con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
{
    while ( (str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into table_name values ('" + str + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My code might be wrong/inefficient. So, feel free to correct me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

BULK INSERT TABLE_NAME
FROM 'file path'
WITH
(ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

**When you giving the path You should give server path.otherwise query will get error **